# Lag between loading new scene in Unity

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity3d-2dtools

I'm using this to load a new scene with a UI button:

```
public void game1start() {
        Application.LoadLevel ("gameScene1");
    }
```

This is between a "choose scene" where you pick a level and the game scene. Currently there is a 3 second delay between the scenes. How can I reduce the delay? Not sure I can use LoadLevelAdditive as I don't want to keep the UI stuff from the choose scene.

It's an Android game using Unity 5.

Update:

I tried using StartCoroutine with a delay of 0.2 seconds, but the IEnumerator can't be used with a UI button?

Comment: I have same problem if you solved this say me how please !